# Making 3D landscape area appear in Vectorworks 2011

Tags: 3d

I am using Vectorworks 2011 to build a site plan. I would like to include a 3D view using a "Landscape Area" to display a block of vegetation. I have drawn the shape of the area, set the 3D view to "3D Plants" and added the plant information.

When I turn on OpenGL mode and switch to a 3D view the plants appear only as plain grey cross-shaped 3d objects (not sure of the right word!). I can't get them to look like plants either as 3D shapes or 2D images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to view rasters/textures in 3d in Vectorworks you need to have Renderworks installed. Without it you only get 3d vector shapes such as the cross that I mentioned.

[Source](http://techboard.vectorworks.net/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=149959&)

Why they couldn't have added something that at least looks vaguely like a tree, I don't know. I don't mind that it's not photo-realistic (I would have bought Renderworks if I wanted that) but it would be nice if a vegetation object looked at least vaguely like vegetation. Particularly as Landmark example image contains trees or bushes. Just making it green would be a start. As it is my only options are to insert lots of individual trees manually, make a 3d vegetation-shaped object or Photoshop them in afterwards.

Or buy Renderworks.

Answer (score 0):

not familiar with vectorworks.

Autodesk ADT utilizes a view/object system in which the objects placed must be "activated" or symbolized in each view that it is to be used in. You might try to find a template and see if you can get under the hood to see how the objects are enabled.

Object  |    viewname    |      symbol
Tree    |       3d       |     3dtreeblock
Door    |    elevation   |     2ddrelevblock

so forth

HTH